# if statement list-comprehension style

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there is a pythonic way of achieving an if-statement in "list-comprehension style". If it exists, the solution is probably an easy one, but I have no clue where to look this up (or how this is called).

```py
mylist= ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

x = "bar"

mc = MyClass(param1 =foo, param2=bar, is_expected=[x if x in mylist]
```

Depending on the value `x` holds, the value of the parameter `is_expected` should been set (`True` if it's in the list, otherwiese `False`) and passed to the constructor.

Comment: Did you mean: `is_expected=(x in mylist)`?

Comment: ```is_expected=x in mylist```?

Comment: Wow, I’ always wondering how easy python is achieving things. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use
`mc = MyClass(param1 =foo, param2=bar, is_expected = (x in mylist))`

Answer (score 0):

`x in mylist` would return you a bool. If x was in that list, result would be true and if not, result would be false

so you can use `mc = MyClass(param1 =foo, param2=bar, is_expected=x in mylist)`